# NodeJs Unable to make Self Signed Cert work with windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, x509certificate

I've been working on this issue on and off for a few months now I am a point where I need this to work. I have solved this issue with git but not nodejs. An Internal url we have is using a Self-Signed cert because its internal use only. I need to use node to communicate with the url. I've tried to set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS many times with nothing working. One way was suggected to set the environemnt value this way
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS", "C:\Temp\NodeCertFix\selfSignedCert.cer", "Machine") I have confirmed that the cert is a base64 cert, same as a .pem in Linux. No Matter what i do i can't get it to work.

> events.js:180
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
>       at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1317:34)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)
>       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:792:8)
>       at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:606:12) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
>       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {   code:
>   'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY' }

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example) package from npm?